# Nginx redirect dynamic page

Tags: nginx, redirect

I want to redirect the dynamic URL when a user accidentally delete **/en**

for e.g

```
https://myweb.com/en/product/myproduct-1
https://myweb.com/en/product/myproduct-2
https://myweb.com/en/product/myproduct-3
```

so when the user accidentally deletes **/en** then he is still redirected to the web it should be like this:

```
https://myweb.com/en/product/myproduct-1
```

not like this

```
https://myweb.com/product/myproduct-1
```

I've tried like this but failed:

```
location /produk/[a-zA-Z0-9|-]* {
     return 301 https://myweb.com/end/about/[a-zA-Z0-9|-]*;
}
```

how to do the redirect dynamically without having to go one by one, because there are many product pages?

Comment: Try: `location ^~ /product/ { return 301 /en$request_uri; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve by this:

```
location ^~ /product/ { return 301 /en$request_uri; }
```